# Can not read dir-local variable from a hook function

Tags: directory-local-variables, local-variables

hope you are all well.

Before stating problem, let me tell you my setup. I am using `Emacs 27.1`, using `pyvenv`, `projectile`, `lsp-mode`, `lsp-python-ms` for `python-mode`. I have set `WORKON_HOME` environmental variable to `~/.pyenv/versions` and created an env named `venv3.8`. I can activate the venv using `<M-x> pyvenv-workon <RET> venv3.8 <RET>`. After that i can start lsp with `lsp` command.

My idea was to set virtualenv (using `pyvenv-workon`) automatically upon opening a project (python project) or opening a python script (not part of a project). So the concept was like this -

1. If a project is opened, meaning `projectile-project-name` is available first check if there is a virtualenv with the same name, if thats available activate it. If thats not available check a special variable (which i set with `defcustom`) name `python-env-name` for a hint, now if the specified env is available then activate it. Else do nothing.
2. If a standalone script is opened, then check if `pyhton-env-name` for a hint, if the specified env is available, activate it. Else do nothing.
3. After activating the virtualenv, start lsp-mode.

The custom variable `python-env-name` is supposed to be available to set in a `.dir-local.el` so that i can easily set per project venv if necessary.

Here is my current code -

```el
(defcustom python-env-name "venv"
  "Set the virtualenv name to be used.

The virtualenv name is the folder name of a virtualenv
located under WORKON_HOME directory.  It is set to be
~/.pyenv/versions."
  :type 'string
  :tag "Python Virtual Environment Name"
  :group 'python
  :safe 'stringp)

(defun my/log (message)
  "Log MESSAGE to *my-logs* buffer.

MESSAGE is string value."
  (interactive "sMessage: ")
  (if (stringp message)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-logs*")
        (insert message))))

(defun my/activate-venv-for-project ()
  "Activates virtualenv for current project."
  (let ((project-venv-path (concat (getenv "WORKON_HOME") "/"
                                   projectile-project-name))
        (default-venv-path (concat (getenv "WORKON_HOME") "/"
                                   (buffer-local-value 'python-env-name (current-buffer)))))
    (my/log (format "Project venv: %s, found: %s\n" project-venv-path
                    (file-directory-p project-venv-path)))
    (my/log (format "Default venv: %s, found: %s\n" default-venv-path
                    (file-directory-p default-venv-path)))
    (if (file-directory-p project-venv-path)
        (pyvenv-workon projectile-project-name)
      (if (file-directory-p default-venv-path)
          (pyvenv-workon python-env-name)))))

(defun my/activate-venv-for-script ()
  "Activate virtualenv for a standalone script."
  (let ((default-venv-path (concat (getenv "WORKON_HOME") "/"
                                   (buffer-local-value 'python-env-name (current-buffer)))))
    (my/log (format "Script default venv: %s, found: %s\n" default-venv-path
                    (file-directory-p default-venv-path)))
    (if (file-directory-p default-venv-path)
        (pyvenv-workon python-env-name))))
(defun my/setup-python-environment ()
  "Setup the python virtual env for project or python script.

This function first checks if we opened a project, if so either the
virtualenv named as the projectile-project-name or the value of
python-env-name will be used to activate virtualenv.  If none are
aviable no virtualenv will be activated.  If we didnt open any
project, then simply check the python-env-name variable, if
the env is available then activate it or not.  Afterwards it will
start up lsp-mode."
  (interactive)
  (hack-local-variables-apply)
  (hack-dir-local-variables)
  (if (bound-and-true-p projectile-project-name)
      (my/activate-venv-for-project)
    (my/activate-venv-for-script))
  (require 'lsp-python-ms)
  (lsp))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/setup-python-environment)
```

As you can see, i tried to show some message while setting up the environment. Then i opened a python project (using projectile), and opened a python file. I have already set the `python-env-name` in a dir-local file as follows -

```
((python-mode . ((python-env-name . "venv3.8"))))
```

Here is the text from `*my-logs*` buffer -

```
Project venv: ~/.pyenv/versions/python-check, found: nil
Default venv: ~/.pyenv/versions/venv, found: nil
```

So clearly, the dir-local value is not used in the `my/setup-python-environment`. But if i put the cursor at the python file and run `<M-x> eval-expression <RET> python-env-name <RET>` it shows `"venv3.8"` in the minibuffer. So the dir local variables are read. What am i doing wrong? Please help. Forgive my if i am doing anything wrong as i am very new to elisp. Thanks in advance. I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147060/how-can-i-access-directory-local-variables-in-my-major-mode-hooks answer your question?

Comment: This did solve my problem. For anyone else coming to this page, i have used @phils's answer to the stackoverflow question. It did solve my problem.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are set after hooks are run. Try using a timer:

```el
(let ((buf (current-buffer)))
  (run-with-timer 0.01 nil
          (lambda ()
            (with-current-buffer buf
              (if (bound-and-true-p projectile-project-name)
                (my/activate-venv-for-project)
               (my/activate-venv-for-script))
              (require 'lsp-python-ms)
              (lsp)))))
```

Comment: I tried the timer solution, but got an error saying buf is void variable.

Comment: Is lexical binding enabled?